# Query jsonb array and return search index

Tags: postgresql

I've the following dataset

```
Table 1
-------
Id | JsonB
1  | [ { "Name": "ABC" }, { "Name": "DEF" } ]
2  | [ { "Name": "XYZ" }, { "Name": "ABC" } ]
3  | [ { "Name": "GHI" }, { "Name": "JKL" } ]
```

I want to return the index of the value in search. For example when searching for `{"Name": "ABC"}` it would return the below result. Note: my search is on a unique property, however just in case if there are more than one occurrence it can return an array of indexes.

```
Query result
--------------------
Id | Index
1  | [0]
2  | [1]
3  | null or []
```

EDIT: because Postgresql works with paths and in case of nested search, may it's better to return the path instead, but I am happy with any

```
Query result
--------------------
Id | Path
1  | ['{0}']
2  | ['{1}']
3  | null or []
```

Comment: What's the expected result when a name occurs multiple times in the array?

Comment: @Bergi for general purpose I don't know, but for my case I am querying a unique property I've control on

Comment: @Bergi may be it can be an array of all occurrences

Comment: what means do you wanr 2 if ABC is twice the or 1

Comment: "*in case of nested search, may it's better to return the path instead*" - that would be very hard. Postgres supports nested search with the jsonpath `**` operator, but provides no way to generate a path from that; you'd have to write a recursive SQL function to traverse nested arrays/objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the result as a JSON array, not a PostgreSQL array, you could use

```
SELECT json.id,
       nullif(jsonb_agg(u.n - 1), '[null]')
FROM json
   LEFT JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(json.jsonb) WITH ORDINALITY AS u(e, n)
      ON u.e = '{"Name": "ABC"}'
GROUP BY json.id;
```

`jsonb_array_elements()` unnests the JSON array and `WITH ORDINALITY` gibes us the position in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `jsonb_array_elements` table function to extract the objects to match against and the `WITH ORDINALITY` option to generate an index. Put them in a subquery and aggregate the indices of the matched objects back into an array:

```
SELECT
  id,
  (
    SELECT array_agg(ord-1)
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(array_of_objects) WITH ORDINALITY AS values(obj, ord)
    WHERE obj = '{ "Name": "ABC" }'
  ) AS index
FROM demo;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/m3GXMdrL))</sup>

Notice I've used `ord - 1` to make the index 0-based, ordinality (and array indexing) is 1-based in Postgres.

If there is no match, `array_agg` will return `NULL`, to get an empty array instead, wrap the subquery in `ARRAY(…)`. Or if you want a json array, use `COALESCE((SELECT json_agg(…) FROM …), '[]')`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements` with ordinality to get the position of each element :

```
SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(ordinality- 1) as index
FROM mytable 
LEFT JOIN jsonb_array_elements(myjson) with ordinality
      ON value = '{"Name": "ABC"}'
GROUP BY id
ORDER By id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/8uPXCziu)

Comment: Don't convert all the json objects to text just for the comparison.